# REST API reference for Windows Store for Business

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store

Does anyone have any experience using the REST API reference for Windows Store for Business (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/mt608306(v=vs.85).aspx)?

I'm trying to use it to but having authorization issues.  Does anyone know what needs to be passed over for authorization when using the api?

Answer (score 2):

Then Store for Business service reply on Azure Directory for authentication. The management toll must be registered as an Azure AD application within an organization tenant to authenticate against the Store for business. About configuring your Azure AD application you could refer to [this document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/mt608307%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

To learn more about Azure Ad and how to register your application within Azure Ad, here are some topics to get your started:

•   Adding an application to Azure Active Directory - [Azure Active Directory integration with MDM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/mt158260(v=vs.85).aspx)

•   Accessing other Web applications and configuring your application to access other APIs - [Integrating Applications with Azure Active Directory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-integrating-applications/)

•   Authenticating to the Store for Business services via Azure AD - [Authentication Scenarios for Azure Active Directory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-scenarios/)